# Passing a variable name as a parameter to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a function that accepts `kwargs`, but the argument name is being retrieved from a separate process and is unknown before hand.

For example:

```py
param = 'desired_param'

some_function(desired_param=5)
```

The problem is that I don't know the content of the `param` and so have to somehow pass it to `some_function`.

Is it possible to pass the content of the `param` to the function with a value?

`some_function` is not something I defined, so I don't have any control over it.

Comment: So based on the TYPE of  `param` you want to pass it to different parameter of the `some_function` yes? If it's `Int` then to `param_int` and if `String` then to `param_str` for example?

Comment: I believe your question has the answer in this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: You can expand dictionary key/values as keyword parameters.  `d = {'desired_param':5}`, `some_function(**d)`.

Comment: the name of the param is what I need to pass to the function, for example if it's `desired_param`, call would be `some_function(desired_param=5), but if `param` is `other`, call would be `some_function(other=5)`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Awesome! thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Use keyword expansion:

```
param = 'desired_param'
d = {param:5}
some_function(**d)
```

Or even shorter:

```
param = 'desired_param'
some_function(**{param:5})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_function(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

param = 'desired_param'
my_kwargs = {param:5}
some_function(**my_kwargs)
```

output

```
{'desired_param': 5}
```